# Get Prev/Next post link via post ID in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently using the WordPress `previous_post_link` and `next_post_link`, which work as expected. The issue is that I have imported tons of posts via CSV file, so now most posts have the same date/timestamp, and WP doesn't pick the right prev/next post as it is based on date by default I believe.
I have searched other answers which show how to search the ID, but I can't seem to implement it into a link, it only returns a plain ID. For sure I'm getting it wrong as I do not have much PHP knowledge.

I am using this code:

```
<div class="prev"><?php previous_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>&nbsp;</div>
<div class="next"><?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>&nbsp;</div>
```

I have found the code below but I don't know how to turn it into the code format above.

```
<?php
function get_previous_post_id( $post_id ) {
    global $post;
    $oldGlobal = $post;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $previous_post = get_previous_post();
    $post = $oldGlobal;
    if ( '' == $previous_post ) 
        return 0;
    return $previous_post->ID; 
} 

echo get_previous_post_id( $current_id );
```

An answer that can provide a working code is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify. When you mention the "next" post, do you mean the one with the next highest ID?

Comment: @O.Jones Yes. If I'm on post with id 10, next post would be id 11, previous would be id 9 (or whichever number falls before/after)

Comment: I think the most appropriate way to do this, would be to overwrite the ORDER BY clause in the database query this executes, via the provided hook. https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1941

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately I don't have access to the database, I could request it, but if there is a solution that avoids that it's better. Thanks

Comment: I am not talking about _you_ accessing the database, manually, outside of the WordPress system - but about modifying the query that _WordPress_ will execute. (And your WP obviously _has_ database access.)

Comment: The hook suggestion does not  require database access, only php. It's an excellent suggestion. If @CBroe doesn't write it up I will.

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe pointed out a couple of filter hooks allowing a programmer to control the meaning of "next" and "previous".

(WordPress customization code is all about [hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/). If you don't know much about them, you would be wise to find out more.)

The hooks he suggests, `get_next_post_sort` and `get_previous_post_sort`, give us php programmers a way to intervene in the database queries to look up next and previous posts.

This code does it. It tells the database to order by id, then post date. The usual `$order` clause has this value `"ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1"`, and this filter adds `p.ID` after the date. Therefore posts with identical dates will be ordered by ID, which is what you say you need.

```php
/** Filter to disambiguate identical-date post ordering.
 *
 * @param string  $order_by  Usually "ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1"
 * @param WP_Post $post      The current post object.
 * @param string  $order     Either 'ASC' or 'DESC'
 *
 * @returns string The modified $order_by string.
 */
function redibis_next_prev_by_id ( $order_by, $post, $order ) {
    return "ORDER BY p.post_date $order, p.ID $order LIMIT 1";
}

add_filter ( 'get_next_post_sort', 'redibis_next_prev_by_id', 10, 3 );
add_filter ( 'get_prev_post_sort', 'redibis_next_prev_by_id', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Unable to get it to work. It gives error. Where should I add that code?

Comment: I made a mistake, apologies. I've added two parameters to each add_filter call.

Comment: But my solution isn't enough to solve the problem, as I discovered while debugging. You'll need to work on the WHERE clause, not just the ORDER BY clause. See [this](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/1e9ba110797d131c3b012586512aacab580a8f55/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1897). I think a complete and working solution is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Adjusting the post dates is certainly your most robust solution.

Comment: I have now automatically changed the dates indeed, as it seemed easier. Thanks